# How to read a GBK-encoded file into a String?

Tags: rust

```
use std::env;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let filename = &args[1];
    let mut f = File::open(filename).expect("file not found");
    let mut contents = String::new();
    f.read_to_string(&mut contents).expect("something went wrong reading the file");
    println!("file content:\n{}", contents);
}
```

When I attempt to read a [GBK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK) encoded file, I get the following error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'something went wrong reading the file: Error { repr: Custom(Custom { kind: InvalidData, error: StringError("stream did not contain valid UTF-8") }) }', /checkout/src/libcore/result.rs:860
```

It says the stream must contain valid UTF-8. How can I read a GBK file?

Comment: Why not use `read_to_end` to get the bytes without decoding to `String`?

Comment: @Veedrac I need to read line by line, any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out how to read line by line from a GBK-encoded file.

```
extern crate encoding;

use std::env;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io::BufReader;

use encoding::all::GBK;
use encoding::{Encoding, EncoderTrap, DecoderTrap};

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let filename = &args[1];

    let mut file = File::open(filename).expect("file not found");
    let reader = BufReader::new(&file);

    let mut lines = reader.split(b'\n').map(|l| l.unwrap());

    for line in lines {
        let decoded_string = GBK.decode(&line, DecoderTrap::Strict).unwrap();
        println!("{}", decoded_string);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You likely want the [`encoding`](https://crates.io/crates/encoding) crate.

Comment: yes, I know there's a `encoding` crate which can decode or encode between different encodings.   But, it run into errors where I called `f.read_to_string(&mut contents)` ,before I can do some encoding work. How can I read the content into String?

Comment: @Will You can't, that's the point.  You have to read the file as bytes, then use `encoding` to decode it into a String.

Comment: how to read the file as bytes line by line? I know `read_to_end `, but I need to read line by line because the file is too big to load into memory.

Comment: @Will: If, for some reason, you can't just decode the entire file at once then you'll need to do line splitting manually.  In any case, this has now turned into a different question, and I'm not playing Question Tennis.